# A partial of the text background didn't appear after adding new a and span in the same div

Tags: html, css

I have a minor or a glitch problem. Anyone can tell me the reason why "Log Out" from [imgA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhmDK.png) turn to [imgB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGGPn.png). This happen when I put new lines which has been commented as "// New!!" in the HTML codes given. The problem occur on the "right" div. I provide the whole codes for the header.

CSS codes for left and mid div

```
.header {
    background: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 50px;
    flex-flow: row;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.header > #left {
    background: transparent;
    color: #535659;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 70px;
}
.header > #left:after,
.header > #left:before {
    background: rgba(0, 173, 181, 0.6);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 30px;
}
.header > #left:before {
    background: rgba(250, 85, 85, 0.8);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0%;
    left: 30px;
}
.header > #mid {
    background-color: teal;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

CSS codes for right div

```
.header > #right {
    background: transparent;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header > #right > .logout {
    background: #FA5555;
    border: 2px solid #FA5555;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 }
.header > #right > .option {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML codes ([imgA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhmDK.png) when there is no "// New!!", [imgB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGGPn.png) after adding ""// New!!". NOTES: "// New!!" is just a deco I put here to highlight the lines that affecting the problem. In the real HTML files, I didn't put it.)

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="left"><b>SPAP</b>r</div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="right">
        <a class="option" onclick=""><span>Register</span></a> // New!!
        <a class="option" onclick=""><span>Settings</span></a> // New!!
        <a class="logout" onclick=""><span>Log Out</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: So when you add the two new anchors they simply move the login button over and place themselves in the order in which you coded them. Anchor tags are inline elements so they will be placed on one line as apposed to block level elements that get their own line.  I guess what I am asking is what would you like for these two new anchors to do that they are not doing already?  What would you like your final result to be?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow 53iky0,

a double slash "//" is used to comment things out in JavaScript if you would like to comment something out in HTML you will need to use "`<!-- -->`" so just change

```
// New!!
```

to

```
<!-- New!! -->
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ahh.. sorry the // New !! I add in the HTML just acting as pointer here. Since the real code there is no "// New!!". Thanks for teliing me anyway.

Comment: Ok, sorry misread the question I will take another look at it in a minute